# Visual Basic WebBrowser: How to add Local HTML file URL?

Tags: html, vb.net, forms, local

I've been pouting about all over Google, but can't seem to find a solution to this. I have added a reg key and everything works fine, until I want to open a local file. I have this code with the ' comment snippets on what I've tried including the last one I've tried:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\...\...\......\index.html")
        'WebBrowser1.Navigate(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) &     "\index.html")
        'WebBrowser1.Document.Write(IO.File.ReadAllText("index.html"))
        'WebBrowser1.Navigate("file:///" & IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\index.html"))
        'WebBrowser1.Navigate(App.Path & "\index.html")

        Dim strLocation As String

        strLocation = "c:\Users\...\...\...\index.html"
        strLocation = "file://" & strLocation

        WebBrowser1.Navigate(strLocation)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Everytime before testing, I build, and move the exe file is in the same folder and run it. All I get is a blank page and some time later "Not Responding" and shuts down.

Comment: I normally use this control in JScript through WSH, so my answer may not be relevant here. But have you tried using a forward slash? Either "c:/Users/..." or the same with "file://c:/Users/..."?

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the reply.
Unfortunately yes, I have :/

Comment: Actually, you were right Tim, I reversed the slash and it worked. But I tried it on a simple html file, it still crashes for my original one.

Comment: How does your original html file differ from the simple one?

Comment: Original is an html file linked to a javascript file which loads over 4000 images and a few sound files. Simple one loads 3 images with similar code.
I've tried setTimeout() for 20 seconds to wait for files to load before initializing program, it crashed right on the nth second, however long I put for.
Everything runs fine though in a regular browser.

Comment: Oh and simple folder size is 1.6MB, original 42MB. Is it maybe possible webbrowser has processing/ram limits?

Comment: Wow. I'd stay away from displaying 4000 images no matter what... an infinite scroll pattern might work better for that page. It is also possible the WebBrowser control is rendering the page in an older document mode that is not compatible with your code. What happens if you log out the document.documentMode and document.compatMode in the html page though javascript? Does it report the same values as when you open the html page directly in the browser?

Comment: Haha, doesn't display them all together, just loads them. It's a game :) I tested it out on one of my other games with a folder of 1000 image, even though double the size, works great. I guess I just need to start being more efficient.
Thanks again for all your help Tim, I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Just to clarify, was the original problem fixed by adding forward slashes or  by fixing your html page? It would be nice to close out this question with an answer.

Comment: Fixing slashes and trying it on something that required less processing. Thanks again!